# Objetos dentro de un array en JavaScript -> generar un nuevo array con propiedades del objeto anidado

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Cómo están. Tengo un problemón que ya no sé si es conceptual o porque soy muy nueva y entiendo todo por la mitad. Teniendo este objeto literal :

```
const persona = {
nombre: 'Fulano',
apellido: 'DeTal',
peliculas: [{titulo: 'Yo Robot', director: 'Alex Proyas'}, {titulo: 'IA', director: 'Steven Spilberg'}],

nombresDePeliculas(){ 
MÉTODO QUE TODAVÍA NO PUEDO DESCRIFRAR
}
};
```

En el método **nombresDePeliculas** debe generar un nuevo array solamente con los títulos de las películas que se encuentran dentro del array 'películas'. Intenté varias cosas, el último código al que llegué es el siguiente:

```
let listado = [];
for (let libro of objeto.libros){
 listado = objeto['libros']['titulo'].push(libro)
  }
return listado;
```

}

En la consola me figura este mensaje: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
Sospecho que estaría teniendo un desencuentro conceptual y de sintaxis en algún lado, probé métodos for tradicionales, intenté con un map, pero en ningún caso lo conseguí. Busqué en diferentes tutoriales (en video y demás) pero no encontré nada. Este es un pedido desesperado de ayuda, tuve pesadillas toda la noche con este código, jajajajaja.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por la atención :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) recorre un arreglo y devuelve uno nuevo, donde cada elemento es el valor devuelto internamente, por ejemplo:

```
// El primer parámetro es el que usarás para acceder a cada elemento
persona.peliculas.map(function(pelicula) {
    // El valor que devuelvas aquí es lo que contendrá
    // cada elemento del nuevo arreglo
    return pelicula.titulo;
});
```

Usando [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) se puede resumir a una sola línea.

```
persona.peliculas.map(pelicula => pelicula.titulo);
```

> [Sintaxis Básica](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#sintaxis_b%C3%A1sica): Un parámetro. Con una expresión simple no se necesita return

```js
const persona = {
    nombre: 'Fulano',
    apellido: 'DeTal',
    peliculas: [
        {titulo: 'Yo Robot', director: 'Alex Proyas'},
        {titulo: 'IA', director: 'Steven Spilberg'}
    ],
    nombresDePeliculas() {
        // Esto es un método de objeto
        // -- Se usa this para acceder a otras propiedades
        // Crear arreglo nuevo con solo título de película
        return this.peliculas.map(pelicula => pelicula.titulo);
    }
};

// Comprobar funcionamiento
console.log(persona.nombresDePeliculas());
```

Por otra parte, no es recomendable crear directamente las propiedades de un objeto en la forma que lo estás haciendo, porque no permite flexibilidad. Lo apropiado es crear una clase que se pueda inicializar con datos específicos para cada elemento. Pero supongo que el código que pusiste es solo un ejemplo y posteriormente lo adaptarás a un ejercicio más adecuado.

Answer (score 0):

No sé cómo habrás codeado el .map, pero a mi me funciona esto:

````
nombre: 'Fulano',
apellido: 'DeTal',
peliculas: [{titulo: 'Yo Robot', director: 'Alex Proyas'}, {titulo: 'IA', director: 'Steven Spilberg'}],
nombresDePeliculas() {
  return this.peliculas.map((pelicula) => {
    return pelicula.titulo
  })
}
}
console.log(persona.nombresDePeliculas()) ```

Espero te sirva y dejes de tener pesadillas ;)

Un saludo
````

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).